# assign value to variable when clicke on button inside foreach loop in php blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have been using angular js to develope web applications and i am quite fan of it. Just starting my hands on laravel 5 to learn something new. I am trying to find angular's ng-click replacement in laravel for blelow situation.

I am using simple html (no php form tags) to insert some data and display it in php blade templete using blade's @foreach control sturcture like below

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

          <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Name of value</th>
                            <th></th>
          </tr>     
          @foreach( $values as $index=>$value)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->value_name}}</td>

                            <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editValueModal" onclick="<?php $selectedValue = $value ?>">Edit</button></td>
          </tr> 
          @endforeach


         </table>
```

data is being displayed properly. As you can see on click "edit" button i open a popup . Now here the problem comes. I am trying to display the value_name in the popup whose edit button is being clicked. i tried to use html's onclick function to set a variable for the correspoiding $value object but it is always setting the last $value of loop in the variable $selectedValue.

Can some please tell me the way i can do it.

Comment: What's the value you are passing in the view?

Comment: i am passing an array of objects to the view from php controller having two properties for each object id and value_name

Comment: Can you use print_r($values); after your values variable?

Comment: i have used {{$values}} on the view and i can see an array of two objects coming like this... [{"id":"1","value_name":"value1","created_at":"2015-08-28 17:20:38","updated_at":"2015-08-28 17:20:38"},{"id":"2","value_name":"value2","created_at":"2015-08-30 10:51:18","updated_at":"2015-08-30 10:51:18"}] .. data is being populated in repeated rows properly

Comment: but every time i click the edit button the popup gets populated with "value2" only  no matter which ever edit button i click.

Comment: I've post my answer @Pawan Rawat

Comment: Try this `onclick="<?php $selectedValue = "this.value"?>"`

Comment: this.value gives error(unknown constant) .. i used this                    onclick="<?php $selectedState= $this->value_name ; ?>" but it says property value_name undefined. doesn't $this refer to $value object ?

Comment: had to use what i didn't want.... used angular's ng-click (always saviour ) ! still the question is open for other options inside blade only ....

Comment: No because it is not declare in the foreach loop so use `$value->value_name`

Comment: How about --- onclick="<?php $selectedValue = $value[$index] ?>

Comment: no this also doesn't work. i tried to use Log::info to see what happens when i click the edit button. What i found out that onclick code on edit button is already called twice while preparing the page and when i click to edit button the event is not fired. Since it is already called twice so it is always assigning the $selctedValue the values of second object

Comment: @Pawan Rawat. How about passing your data in javascript?

Comment: yeah that works. i did it using javascript. i was trying if laravel provides any such solution in itself

Comment: `onclick="<?php $selectedValue = $value ?>"` this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `{{--*/ $abc = 0  /*--}}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.